# Array element not storing previous values only printing last value stored

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class library{

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

public void NMQ(){
    System.out.println("Enter the no of checking");
    int z=s.nextInt();
    for(int e=0; e<z;e++) {
    System.out.println("Number of pages + Number of Tron pages + Number of Readers");
    
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int m = s.nextInt();
    int q = s.nextInt();

    boolean[] book = new boolean[n];
    for (int j = 0; j <n; j++) {
        book[j] = true;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Enter the troned pages:");
    for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
        int tornPage = s.nextInt();
        tornPage= tornPage-1;
        
        book[tornPage] = false;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Enter the readers multiple:");
    int[] readers = new int[q];
    for (int j = 0; j < q; j++) {
        int readerPage = s.nextInt();
        readers[j] = readerPage;
    }
    int totalPageSum= 0;
    int[] t = new int[z];
    for (int j = 0; j < q; j++) {
        int readerNum = readers[j];
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            if (book[k] == true) {
                if (k % readerNum == 0) {
                    totalPageSum++;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    t[e] = totalPageSum;
    if(z==e+1) {
    for(int p=0;p<z;p++) {
    System.out.println("case #"+(p+1)+" "+ t[e]);
}
    }
    }
    }
}


public class customized {

public static void main(String[] args){
    library li = new library();
    
    li.NMQ();
    
} 
}
```

Array element not storing previous values only printing last value stored in array. In this code t[e] printing only the last value stored. Why it doesn't store any previous value ? And I want my output be like case #1 t[0], case #2 t[1] and so on. And I want to get my multiple inputs from single line.

Answer (score 0):

Its normal that t[e] holds only the last value because you only assign one value to that array. if you want to have multiple values you should put it in your for-loop like t[i].

Comment: I don't get it. Please help to understand with more information.

Comment: Read this to see how arrays work : [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). Feel free to ask if you have any questions.